# How can I detect when a user really released a key in Java?

Tags: java, key, keylistener

If you press a key, the player goes forward, but if you hold the key a bit longer the player moves too long in the same direction.
I am using this code to check what key the player is pressing:

```
private void KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

    key = evt.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {

            direction = 1;

            PlayerMovement();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {

            direction = 2;

            PlayerMovement();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {

            direction = 3;

            PlayerMovement();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            direction = 4;
            PlayerMovement();

        }
}
```

Comment: When a user releases a key, you'll get a `KeyReleased` event. Relying on the frequency of `KeyPressed` events is just asking for trouble.

Comment: You're operating based on KeyEvent which I believe is too general. You might try KeyPressed alone or KeyTyped (when the character is entered).

Comment: KeyBindins API is also a good place to look. KeyListener frequently has focus issues

Comment: yea i get a keyReleased event, but after the whole process. Thats to late. For example after I hold a key the cycle starts, that means when I hold a key 2 seconds the event gets into a cycle and after 6 animations my player stops, because the keyReleased event Triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use keyReleased !!! if you need to move the player one step in evry key press
keyPressed keeps running when the user is pressing the key

use THREADS because here you are using the program but if you start a thread you can do what ever you want the program still works fine 
learn about thread because game are all about threads

```
private class Walk_thread extends java.lang.Thread{

public void run(){
//call the walk methode here
PlayerMovement();
}
}
```

so when the key is pressed create a thread that call playermovement

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {

        direction = 1;
new Walk_thread().start();//here the method run is called 
System.out.println("program will not stop the thread is walking and the program is continued too");
    }
```

Comment: but it runs to much if I hold a key 2 seconds my player stops after 4 Animtions thats far to long

Comment: use a boolean variable true when is pressed the thread will move the player and sleep some time when the user release the key suspend the thread thread are very useful read about it

Comment: can you give me an example pls i dont know exactly what you mean.

Comment: this is a simple exemple but it doesn't work it just for you to understand thread

Comment: and where is the example?

Comment: thank you very much, I tried it and it worked, but now I have a other problem. The player moves much to fast.

Comment: you can add sleep(1000) instraction in the run of the thread sleep(long) the thread will sleep some time before contenu it work 

 try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

Comment: if you want the thread to stop a little youse sleep, wait,stop,suspend,resum they are all useful function